# Count how many times each string from a column appear (no exact match) in another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

My data looks like this 
 
 `df <- data.frame(id = c("p3", "p5", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11"), pedi = c("p1/p2", "p3/p4", "p3/p5", "(p3/p4)/p5", "p5/p8", "p4/p10"))`
 
 I am trying this

```
id <- df$id 
for (i in length(id)) {
  df$id_in_pedi <- sum(grepl(i, df$pedi))
}
```

But it does not work. The result I am looking for is this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("p3", "p5", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11"),
                 pedi = c("p1/p2", "p3/p4", "p3/p5", "(p3/p4)/p5", "p5/p8", "p4/p10"),
                 id_in_pedi = c(3,3,1,0,1,0))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(id_in_pedi = str_count(toString(pedi), id))

   id       pedi id_in_pedi
1  p3      p1/p2          3
2  p5      p3/p4          3
3  p8      p3/p5          1
4  p9 (p3/p4)/p5          0
5 p10      p5/p8          1
6 p11     p4/p10          0
```

in Base R:
Using `sapply`:

```
transform(df, id_in_pedi = colSums(sapply(id, grepl, pedi, USE.NAMES = FALSE)))

   id       pedi id_in_pedi
1  p3      p1/p2          3
2  p5      p3/p4          3
3  p8      p3/p5          1
4  p9 (p3/p4)/p5          0
5 p10      p5/p8          1
6 p11     p4/p10          0
```

Using `Vectorize`:

```
colSums(Vectorize(grepl)(df$id, list(df$pedi)))
 p3  p5  p8  p9 p10 p11 
  3   3   1   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
 table(factor(unlist(strsplit(df$pedi, "[/()]")), levels = df$id))
```

-output

```
  p3  p5  p8  p9 p10 p11 
  3   3   1   0   1   0
```